# GWT Close Popup Panels properly?

Tags: gwt, popup, panel, parent-child

I want close a Popup Panel clicking an anchor, but this anchor could be inside several panels, then go through parents is not a good idea.

How can I get the Popup Panel where the anchor is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just passing a variable with the `PopupPanel` into the other panels?

```
public class PanelWithPopup extends Composite
{
    FlowPanel thisPanel = new FlowPanel();
    PopupPanel popup = new PopupPanel();
    SomeOtherPanel otherPanel;

    public PanelWithPopup()
    {
        // pass the popup panel to the SomeOtherPanel
        otherPanel = new SomeOtherPanel(popup);

        thisPanel.add(otherPanel);
        initWidget(thisPanel);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherPanel
{
    PopupPanel popup;

    public SomeOtherPanel(PopupPanel p)
    {
        this.popup = p;
    }

    void hidePopup()
    {
        popup.hide();
    }
}
```

Or, if the other panels were defined inside the main panel (i.e. if the `SomeOtherPanel` was defined within the `PanelWithPopup`), you could access the `PopupPanel popup` directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close all open popup panels.  Eg: If the user clicks the back button, or your anchor button triggers a page change.  You can use this method:

```
public static void closeAllPopups() {
    for (int i=0; i<RootPanel.get().getWidgetCount(); i++) {
        if (RootPanel.get().getWidget(i) instanceof PopupPanel) {
            PopupPanel popupPanel = (PopupPanel)RootPanel.get().getWidget(i);
            Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(() -> popupPanel.hide());
        }
    }
}
```